# ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to __construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have faced a problem while inject doctrine service in custom class.
I am using symfony 2.3. I have tried all the way but still I am not able to find where is issue and what is missing.
Following is my code :

**config.yml**

```
imports:
   - { resource: parameters.yml }
   - { resource: security.yml }
   - { resource: "@ClCommonBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

**services.yml:**

```
parameters: 
    cl.pager.class: Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers\Pager

services:
    cl.pager:
      class: cl\CommonBundle\Helpers\Pager
      arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

**pagerinterface.php**

```
<?php

namespace Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers;

interface pagerInterface {

    public function getTotalRows($params);
}?>
```

**pager.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers;

use Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers\pagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * Description of pagination
 */
class pager implements pagerInterface {

    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getTotalRows($params) {
        return $this->em->getRepository($params['repository'])->getActiveRowsCount($params);
    }

}?>
```

**Citycontroller.php**

```
namespace Cl\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType;
use Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\City;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers\pager;

class CityController extends Controller {

    public function listAction(Request $request, $trigger = "next", $page = 1, $country, $cityname, $isactive) {

        $pager = new pager();

    }

}?>
```

**Error**

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers\pager::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php on line 117 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/CommonBundle/Helpers/pager.php line 17

in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/CommonBundle/Helpers/pager.php line 17
at ErrorHandler->handle('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers\pager::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php on line 117 and defined', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/CommonBundle/Helpers/pager.php', '17', array()) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/CommonBundle/Helpers/pager.php line 17
at pager->__construct() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php line 117
at CityController->listAction(object(Request), 'next', '4', 'all', 'all', 'all')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CityController), 'listAction'), array(object(Request), 'next', '4', 'all', 'all', 'all')) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2889
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2863
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2992
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2272
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/web/app_dev.php line 29


Stack Trace

in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php at line 162  -
                        }
                    });
                    throw new DummyException();
                }
            }
at ErrorHandler ->handle ('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers\pager::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php on line 117 and defined', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/CommonBundle/Helpers/pager.php', '17', array())
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/CommonBundle/Helpers/pager.php at line 17  +
at pager ->__construct ()
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/src/Cl/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php at line 117  +
at CityController ->listAction (object(Request), 'next', '4', 'all', 'all', 'all')
at call_user_func_array (array(object(CityController), 'listAction'), array(object(Request), 'next', '4', 'all', 'all', 'all'))
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2889  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2863  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2992  +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2272  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/web/app_dev.php at line 29  +

Logs  - 1 error

DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
INFO - Matched route "_admin_city_list" (parameters: "_controller": "Cl\AdminBundle\Controller\CityController::listAction", "trigger": "next", "page": "4", "country": "all", "cityname": "all", "isactive": "all", "_route": "_admin_city_list")
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Read SecurityContext from the session
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException".
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\DummyException: "" at /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php line 162
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

Comment: Delete this 3rd import form config.yml Let the DI do this his work.

Comment: ok let me check to delete

Comment: there is no difference after delete

Comment: Hmmm.  Three people have given you the correct answer and you rejected them all.  Might be a pattern here.  new pager() has no relationship with the service container.  It simply will not work.  Accept it and move on.

Comment: Cerad, I just ask about my confusion. I am also appreciate and thankful to them. I don't know why are you criticize about my comment, You had same before this.

Comment: Have you considered reading the manual? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html  And if you have found some article suggesting that the php new operator will use the symfony dependency injection container then please post a link.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller replace `$pager = new pager();` with `$pager = $this->get('cl.pager');`
This will invoke `service container` to load your service and inject `objectManager` to constructor

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, I had asked same question to jamek and ahmed also, so please don't bored, I required to clarification and solution of methodology to implement. it's a way to call container in external class. but symfony 2.3 also provide way to call entitymanager object via constructor in external class. there are lots of site provide same option but I am not succeed. so can you explain how could I implement it. I have tried lot

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure if I understand you well. The thing is that when you define your class as a service you need to use it as a service. Intantiating class using `new` keyword is not a valid way. Symfony2 uses Service Container to handle instantiating services and you should too

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my mean to say that this is single service but what if I want to call multiple services in same class.

Comment: you can pass multiple services as arguments to constructor of other services, your pager for example can take objectManager and session, to do that just extend `arguments` list: `arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","@session"]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your service from container, not by creating new instance

```
namespace Cl\AdminBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType;
    use Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\City;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
    use Cl\CommonBundle\Helpers\pager;

    class CityController extends Controller {

        public function listAction(Request $request, $trigger = "next", $page = 1, $country, $cityname, $isactive) {

            $pager = $this->get('cl.pager'); //

        }

    }?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jamek, same comment and question ask to jamek you also that it's a way to call container in external class. but symfony 2.3 also provide way to call entitymanager object via constructor in external class. there are lots of site provide same option but I am not succeed. so can you explain how could I implement it. I have tried lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you instantiate and call your pager helper:

```
$pager = new pager();
```

You've to let the container create an instance of your pager helper, you've to create an extension to do that:

- [How to Load Service Configuration inside a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)

Then you'll be able to call your helper within your controller as follow,

```
$this->get('cl.pager');
```

Comment: Thanks ahmed, but it's a way to call container in external class. but symfony 2.3 also provide way to call entitymanager object via constructor in external class. there are lots of site provide same option but I am not succeed. so can you explain how could I implement it. I have tried lot

Comment: I don't understand your question. You've to let the container instantiate the pager helper, you'll then have to call this instance from the Sf container. Based on the code you shared, You're trying to create a new instance of Pager without providing the doctrine dependency, which is wrong. The point here is to let us know if you want to define your pager helper as a service or not.